# Usage of tf.name_scope

Tags: tensorflow

My question is about the usage of `tf.name_scope` in the tutorials code  [ptb/reader.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py#L100),

```
  with tf.name_scope(name, "PTBProducer", [raw_data, batch_size, num_steps]):
      #use raw_data, batch_size, num_steps to construct tf objects
```

what's the purpose of calling tf.name_scope with the list [raw_data, batch_size, num_steps]?  `raw_data` is a python list, `batch_size` and `num_steps` are python int. According to the doc for [name_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#name_scope):

`tf.name_scope(name, default_name=None, values=None): This context manager validates that the given values are from the same graph, makes that graph the default graph, and pushes a name scope in that graph (see Graph.name_scope() for more details on that).`

But `raw_data`, `batch_size`, `num_step` are not any node in the graph. What does it mean by validates them are from the same graph? In fact, the code still runs when the list is removed from the tf.name_scope call:

```
      with tf.name_scope(name, "PTBProducer"):
      #use raw_data, batch_size, num_steps to construct tf objects
```

What's the difference of calling `tf.name_scope` with and without the `values=[raw_data,batch_size,num_steps]`?

Answer (score 3):

ptb/reader.py is using the tf.name_scope() **values** argument incorrectly. Graph elements should be passed.

name_scope() will make the default graph context match the graph of the passed in elements. This is useful if you are working on multiple graphs.

tf.name_scope will raise an error if the list of **values** (graph elements) are not all from the same graph.